# Stop CSS3 opacity animation before 1

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a certain div opacity `from` **0** `to` **0.6**, but it seems that at the end of the animation it jumps to **1**.

What am I missing?

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #900;
  animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `animation-fill-mode: forwards` if you want the element's CSS to remain at the last step of the animation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

> Forwards: The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution.

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #900;
  animation: fadein 2s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s forwards;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Didn't know about this `animation-fill-mode`. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the opacity on the element you are animating to the final value?

I believe the rules in a CSS animation stop applying when the animation finishes. I would guess it is animating from 0 to 0.5 and then reverting to 1, 1 being the default opacity since you don't have an opacity specified on the element itself.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You're totally right. I didn't think about this before, makes sense since a didn't set the default opacity.

Comment: @Marco Be aware of that this can cause the element to flash, as it starts with full opacity. I recommend you chose Michael's solution

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this would cause the element to flicker. Interesting, I'll have to experiment with that. It looks like animation-fill-mode would be a great way to fix this problem too! @Marco, you might also look into the CSS "transition" property - it lets you smoothly interpolate certain properties automatically whenever their values change.